# TabHost and Out of Memory

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-tabhost

I am using a tabhost which contains three activities in different tabs. 
Due to too many images for the background UI, this leads to the problem "Out of Memory".
Is it possible to destroy other activities which are not in the current tab, and to reconstruct them if need ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you have many bitmaps?